# Set Warnings (Alerts & Thresholds) in MSSQL Replication Monitor using TSQL

Tags: sql-server, replication, t-sql

How can I configure the settings on this screen in Replication Monitor using TSQL?
[image: Replication Monitor - Warnings page]
For reference, we're on SQL 2014.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Detailed information about programmatically monitoring replications can be found on the official Microsoft Docs site:

Reference: [Programmatically Monitor Replication](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/replication/monitor/programmatically-monitor-replication)

There is detailed information on all the stored procedures required to query monitoring details:

#### To monitor Publishers, publications, and subscriptions from the Distributor

- [sp_replmonitorhelppublisher](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-replmonitorhelppublisher-transact-sql)
- [sp_replmonitorhelppublication](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-replmonitorhelppublication-transact-sql)
- [sp_replmonitorhelpsubscription](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-replmonitorhelpsubscription-transact-sql)

#### To monitor transactional commands waiting to be applied at the Subscriber

- [sp_replmonitorsubscriptionpendingcmd](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-replmonitorsubscriptionpendingcmds-transact-sql)

#### To monitor merge changes waiting to be uploaded or downloaded

- At the Publisher: [sp_showpendingchanges](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-showpendingchanges-transact-sql)

  > returns a result set showing information on changes that are waiting to be replicated to Subscribers
- At the Subscriber: [sp_showpendingchanges](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-showpendingchanges-transact-sql)

  > returns a result set showing information on changes that are waiting to be replicated to the Publisher

#### To monitor Merge Agent sessions

- [sp_replmonitorhelpmergesession](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-replmonitorhelpmergesession-transact-sql) (either at the subscriber or distributor)
- [sp_replmonitorhelpmergesessiondetail](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-replmonitorhelpmergesessiondetail-transact-sql) (either at the subscriber or distributor)

## Answering your question

The stored procedures required to read or change the monitoring thresholds are the `sp_replmontirohelppublicationthresholds` and `sp_replmonitorchangepublicationthreshold` procedures.

#### To view the monitor threshold metrics for a publication

- [sp_replmonitorhelppublicationthresholds](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-replmonitorhelppublicationthresholds-transact-sql)

> ```
> sp_replmonitorhelppublicationthresholds 
>           [ @publisher = ] 'publisher'  
>         , [ @publisher_db = ] 'publisher_db'  
>         , [ @publication = ] 'publication'   
>     [ , [ @publication_type = ] publication_type ]   
>     [ , [ @thresholdmetricname = ] 'thresholdmetricname'
> ```

The parameters are:

`@publisher        : the name of the publisher`
`@publisher_db     : the name of the published database`
`@pbulication      : the name of the publication`
`@publication_type : 0 = transactional publication`
`................    1 = snapshot publication`
`................    2 = merge publication`

#### To modify the monitor threshold metrics for a publication

- [sp_replmonitorchangepublicationthreshold](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-replmonitorchangepublicationthreshold-transact-sql)

> ```
> sp_replmonitorchangepublicationthreshold 
>           [ @publisher = ] 'publisher'  
>         , [ @publisher_db = ] 'publisher_db'  
>         , [ @publication = ] 'publication'   
>     [ , [ @publication_type = ] publication_type ]   
>     [ , [ @metric_id = ] metric_id ]   
>     [ , [ @thresholdmetricname = ] 'thresholdmetricname'   
>     [ , [ @value = ] value ]   
>     [ , [ @shouldalert = ] shouldalert ]   
>     [ , [ @mode = ] mode ]
> ```

The parameters are:

`@publisher        : the name of the publisher`
`@publisher_db     : the name of the published database`
`@pbulication      : the name of the publication`
`@publication_type : 0 = transactional publication`
`................    1 = snapshot publication`
`................    2 = merge publication`
`@metric_id        : 1 = expiration`
`................    2 = latency`
`................    4 = mergeexpiration`
`................    5 = mergeslowrunduration`
`................    6 = mergefastrunduration`
`................    7 = mergefastrunspeed`
`................    8 = mergeslowrunspeed`
`@thresholdmetricname: the name of the publication threshold`
`................      (either this parameter or @metric_id is required)`
`@value            : the new metric value`
`@shouldalert      : generate alert (1=yes;0=no)`
`@mode             : monitoring mode (1=on;2=off)`

Comment: Wow - champion answer! I'll mark it as accepted after I get a chance to run the scripts at work tomororw. Cheers!

Comment: Yep, works beautifully. Thanks for the comprehensive answer addressing both my specific question and the larger question of programmatic monitoring. Cheers!